# How to use live555 streaming media forwarding

Tags: c++, video-streaming, h.264, ondemand, live555

I use Live555 h.264 stream client to query the frame packets from an IP camera, I use ffmpeg to decode the buffer and analysis the frame by OpenCV.(those pipeline are based on [testRTSPClient](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/doxygen/html/testRTSPClient_8cpp-source.html) sample, I decode the h.264 frame buffer in DummySink::afterGettingFrame() by ffmpeg)

And now I wanna stream the frame to another client(remote client) OnDemand mode in real-time, the frame may added the analysis result(boundingboxs, text, etc), how to use Live555 to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your best bet is to re-encode the resultant frame (with bounding boxes etc), and pass this to an RTSPServer process which will allow you to connect to it using an rtsp url, and stream the encoded data to any compatible rtsp client. There is a good reference on the FAQ for how to do this http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/faq.html#liveInput which walks you through the steps taken, and provides example source code which you can modify for your needs.